# Music on Apple Watch without iPhone

Tags: ios, music, apple-watch

**Background**

I'm still working toward my goal of being able to leave my phone in a locker while I work out. Despite the gains of WatchOS 5, it appears that my only real option for music without my phone being nearby is Apple Music (the service) or moving audio files to the watch manually with Apple Music (the app). I'd prefer not to have Apple Music installed on my phone. Googling reveals a lot of articles from the Series 3 release saying that this *should* be possible now, but I've not found any actual solutions.

**Actual Question**

Can I listen to music from my Apple Watch without having my phone nearby and without requiring Apple Music be installed on my phone?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your question is exactly?  Are you looking for an app to listen to music on your Watch or you already have an app and it's not working correctly?

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for saying so. I always struggle to find the balance between adding context and cluttering up the question. It's hopefully improved now, but to answer your question, I'm looking for an app that isn't Apple Music.

Comment: Have you tried Spotify? Does your watch have cellular data?

Comment: To leave your Watch in a locker while you work out, and without putting music directly on the device, you need a cellular Watch.  If cellular, I 'believe' you should be able to use Spotify, iHeartRadio, and Tune-In Radio.  Have you tried any of those?

Comment: Can you clarify if you actually don't want to move audio files to your watch at all, or whether you just don't want to do this with Apple Music? It's not clear from your question which it is? If you're happy to have audio files on your watch, but without Apple Music, this is definitely possible. And, as others have said, if you have a cellular-enabled watch there are other services that will stream music to your watch without Apple Music.

Comment: @dwightk As far as I'm aware, Spotify does not work this way nor does any other music app. It just operates as a remote control for the app on the phone. I confirmed that the Spotify watch app will not play without being able to connect to a phone just now.

Comment: @Monomeeth I do have a cellular watch, and I would be completely happy with either streaming or locally stored audio as long as it didn't require my phone be nearby. I have not found any apps that behave the way you are describing other than Apple Music. Can you clarify how this is possible without using the Apple Music app? I have tried Spotify and Pandora for streaming. I found an app called MixTape since I first asked this question that should be exactly what I want, but is unusably buggy. Is there something else?

Comment: @fsb I am totally happy to put the music locally on the device. Do you know of a way to do this that does not involve installing the Apple Music app on my phone?

Comment: Ah... I saw a headline that "Pandora beats Spotify to offline playback on the Apple Watch" and just remembered it as Spotify might have offline playback.

Comment: @dwightk It does look like Pandora added offline playback last month (Jan 2019) and it does meet my criteria. I'll clarify for others who may find this that it does require a paid subscription and does not support streaming to the watch. But thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

MixTape turns out to be an excellent solution that costs only $3.

http://dorshorst.com/mixtape/

I'm not sure what changed between now and Feb 5th when I first tried it (and commented above) when literally nothing worked but I tried it again today and it worked perfectly for my needs.

As pointed out by @dwightk, Pandora as of 2019 does not support streaming directly to the watch, but does allow you to manually transfer songs to the watch for offline, phone-free listening if you are a Premium subscriber.

So far those are the only two solutions I can find.